# OpenBSD- ignoring a particular keypress

Tags: x11, openbsd, events

I am using a Lenovo Yoga and the screen always sends out some "keystrokes" to indicate its orientation or simply being open, I don't know.

On Linux, I could ignore those keystrokes with `setkeycodes 0x<...> 255` and then go about just fine. But on OpenBSD, the screen keystrokes are making beeps on the xdm login screen, blocking holding keys down by interrupting every now and then, and I know of no way to get around this.

How can I map this keystroke to some void and prevent it from interrupting between my key holds? (and making beeps on login screen)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent solution on OpenBSD to remap keys is to use the `wsconsctl` a utility to configure [wscons(4)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man4/wscons.4?query=wscons&sec=4) driver.

Example from the manpages of [wsconsctl(8)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/wsconsctl.8?query=wsconsctl):

```
wsconsctl keyboard.map+="keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L"
```

> Modify the current keyboard encoding so that, when the Caps Lock key
>   is pressed, the same encoding sequence as Left Control is sent.

**Related Stuff:**

- [FAQ7](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq7.html) - Keyboard and Display Controls

Comment: I used `xev` to obtain keycode 119, but `wsconsctl keyboard.map+="keycode 119=a"` does nothing, like `wsconsctl keyboard.map+="keysym  a=b"`.

Comment: Arent spaces missing inside your command? `wsconsctl keyboard.map+="keycode 119 = a"`

Comment: It does not make difference. It still "maps" the key but the key continues to do nothing. Only if I map the key with `xmodmap` the binding works, but it still interrupts the key hold. What I need is having the kernel completely ignore that keypress.

Comment: can you please test if `xmodmap` works deleting by only using the keycode? `xmodmap -e "remove = 119"`. Cheers.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. `xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad remove modifier input line`.